# Xubuntu and touchscreen

Tags: xubuntu, touchscreen, touchegg

I have a touchscreen laptop and Xubuntu 16.10 installed. By default there is no support of multi-finger gestures. Only left mouse button click when tapping. I install touchegg and touchegg-gce. After it multi-finger gestures were enabled, but left mouse button click emulation doesn't work if I click on window header. I can't move window and use buttons in up-right corner. If I create a gesture in touchegg-gce that emulates LMB click on one finger tap, it emulates two clicks.

How to fix it? Now I want to work with touchscreen as it works without touchegg (LMB click on any place of screen) but with 2 finger scrolling and RMB emulation with 2 finger tapping.

Comment: you need to identify your hardware and file a bug report.

Comment: I think it's not a bug.  And if bug I think it's not connected with my hardware.